# Having issue with Image random caption

Tags: php, css, image

I want to know can I add a caption to this random script

```
<div style="background:transparent url(
 backgrounds/<?php echo 'image-'.rand(0,20).'.jpg'; ?>);"> 
 Welcome to my Site!
</div>
```

There's another way it's using an array for the caption:

```
$images = array(array("image 1" => "caption 1"),
                array("image 2" => "caption 2"),
                array("image 3" => "caption 3");
```

Can I add combine the two of them? Is it possible? If so, how do I do that? 
If there's no way. What else can I do? I appreciate any suggestion

Thanks

Comment: Why does your array look like that? Wouldn't it make more sense to use the filename as the key, and the caption as the value? (Without using a 2d array)

Comment: Hi Truth, It's 2 separate code. I'm trying to add caption to the 1st code. The second code has caption but I want to add caption for the 1st code. I apologizes if I didn't explained it clearly. Sorry about that.

Comment: I understood that, I'm talking about the array on your second snippet. Why does it look like that? Can you change its format?

Comment: No, I mean like this: `array("image1" => "caption 1", "image2" => "caption 2", ...);`

Comment: Hi Truth, I going edited that again! Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could shuffle your `$images` array and grab the first index.

```
$images = array( array('file' => 'image1', 'caption' => 'Caption 1'),
                 array('file' => 'image2', 'caption' => 'Caption 2') );

shuffle($images);
$file = $images[0]['file'];
$caption = $images[0]['caption'];
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks for replying! For the html it's looks like this <div id="shuffle">
<img src="<?php echo $file; ?>"/>
<p id="caption"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>
</div> Is this right based on the changes. I apologize if I wrote it wrong

Comment: Well you would need to make sure the image has a file extension first! `<img src="<?php echo $file; ?>.jpg" />`

Comment: Thanks Marcus for that detail, I think I forgot to write the file extension. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks for the code, it's what I'm looking for. I appreciated you taking time to write this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you have the images array similar to how you say:

```
$images = array(
array('file' => 'image1.jpg',
'caption' => 'Caption 1'),

array('file' => 'image2.jpg',
'caption' => 'Caption 2'),
);
```

You can then get a random entry using `array_rand`:

```
$image_key = array_rand($images);
```

And then you can use this key to give you the image and the caption:

```
<div style="background:transparent url(
 backgrounds/<?php echo $images[$image_key]['file']; ?>);"> 
 <?php echo $images[$image_key]['caption']; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This image is actually better, it does not involve the shuffling of the arrays, which is inefficient.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply and thanks for the example! I forgot about that variable array_rand. It does make sense.

Comment: Hi John, So I replace $images = array(); to $image_key = array_rand();

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the example I will test that out and get to you

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the example I will keep that code in mind. I appreciated you taking time to write this. Thanks!